# ImportError: cannot import name 'estimator_export' from tensorflow (because of an update?)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I was following a audio classification model tutorial a year or two ago, and suddenly, my code doesn't work because of an update that affected how tensorflow and tflite_model_maker were installed.

Because I want to at least save the output of what my code used to do, I am using the fallback runtime on google colab.

`!pip install tflite_model_maker` works because of the runtime change, but now, there is a problem with the imports that used to run smoothly. Here is my code for the imports:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tflite_model_maker as mm
```

And here is the error message:

````
  ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-20-09befa6c6d6d> in <cell line: 2>()
        1 import tensorflow as tf
  ----> 2 import tflite_model_maker as mm
        3 from tflite_model_maker import audio_classifier
        4 import os
        5 

  17 frames
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist- 
  packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py in <module>
       24 from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_lib
       25 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
  ---> 26 from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import estimator_export
       27 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
       28 from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned import head as head_lib

  ImportError: cannot import name 'estimator_export' from 
  'tensorflow.python.util.tf_export' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist- 
  packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_export.py)```
````

Why is this still not running normally, even though I'm using the fallback runtime? And, what can I do to fix this? I already tried installing specific dependencies, but it still doesn't work.